# Primitive recursion

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

how  will i define the function 'simplify' using primitive recursion?

simplify :: Expr -> Expr
    ...

simplify 
Simplify an expression using basic arithmetic, e.g. 
    simplify (Plus (Var "x") (Const 0)) = Var "x"